# Python: Programación orientada a obejtos: Metodo __ str__ para imprimir

Tags: python

Si corren el código la respuesta es El Colibrí mide 10cm. Pero si los parámetros nombre y altura no fueran un string y un int, respectivamente, sino listas, por ejemplo: nombre=['Colibri','Azulejo'] y altura=[10,15], como hago para que cuando imprima la variable de clase Aves, es decir, print(aves), la respuesta sea

El Colibrí mide 10cm

El Azulejo mide 15cm

utilizando el método especial __ str __ para imprimir

```
class Aves:
    def __init__(self,nombre,altura):
        self.n=nombre
        self.a=altura
            
                
    def __str__(self):                
        especie= 'El '+ self.n+' mide ' +str(self.a)+'cm'          
        return especie
                          
   
nombre ='Colibri'
altura = 10
aves = Aves(nombre,altura)
print(aves)
```

Agradezco su comentario, estoy aprendiendo lo relacionado con programación orientada a objetos pero no se como integrar las listas.

Answer (score 0):

Si la versión de python que estás utilizando es mayor a igual a la 3.6 puedes utilizar “f-strings”

```
nombre=['Colibri','Azulejo']
altura=[10,15]

string_ = f"El {nombre[0]} mide {altura[0]}."
```

te comparto un link sobre los [f-strings](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/tutorial-de-f-strings-en-python-formato-de-cadenas-en-python-explicado-con-ejemplos/)

si la versión de python es inferior a la 3.6 puedes utilizar estos otros dos metodos[string-in-python/](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-format-a-string-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

La clase debe llamarse `Ave`, en singular, pues ahí vas a guardar **un** ave. Si quieres guardar **varias** aves, puedes usar una lista como contenedor.

El método `__str__()` sólo debe preocuparse de un imprimir **un** ave. La clase no es un contenedor; no puede tener varias aves adentro.

El código reformulado es:

```
class Ave:
    def __init__(self, nombre, altura):
        self.n = nombre
        self.a = altura

    def __str__(self):
        especie = 'El ' + self.n + ' mide ' + str(self.a) + 'cm'
        return especie


aves = [Ave('Colibri', 10), Ave('Azulejo', 15)]
for ave in aves:
    print(ave)
```

produce:

```
El Colibri mide 10cm
El Azulejo mide 15cm

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Gracias Candid por tus comentarios, fueron de gran ayuda

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de @CandidMoe es el enfoque correcto. La clase `Ave` debe guardar una sola ave y encargarse de imprimir la descripción de una sola ave.

No obstante, si tienes por separado una lista con los nombres de las aves y otra lista con sus longitudes y quieres, a partir de estas listas, crear otra lista con las aves (es decir, otra lista cuyos elementos sean objetos de tipo `Ave`), te resultará útil conocer la existencia de la función `zip()` que permite iterar por varias listas a la vez (dos en este caso) devolviendo tuplas (parejas en este caso) de elementos sacados cada uno de una de las listas.

Es decir, si tienes:

```
nombres = ['Colibri','Azulejo']
alturas = [10,15]
```

entonces `zip(nombres, alturas)` te da un iterador en el que, cada vez que iteres por él, obtendrás una pareja de un nombre y una altura. En la primera iteración sale `('Colibri', 10)` y en la segunda `('Azulejo', 15)`.

Gracias a esto puedes hacer:

```
aves = [ Ave(nombre, altura) for nombre, altura in zip(nombres, alturas) ]
```

Y así ya tendrás la lista de aves sobre la que podrás iterar para obtener la descripción de cada ave:

```
for ave in aves:
    print(ave)
```

Comment: Gracias abulafia por sus comentarios de gran ayuda